# Tildes en apellidos en EEUU / Diacritics with names US

Tags: ortografía, nombres-propios, diacríticos

Mi padre tiene una novia cuyo nombre completo es «Kristen Treviño».  «Kristen» es su nombre de pila, que proviene de sus padres estadunidenses y no hispanohablantes, y «Treviño» es su único apellido, que ella asumió al casarse con su ex marido mexicano pero que guardó aún después del divorcio, ya que lo comparte con su hija.  Por supuesto, en todos los países hispanohablantes, este apellido se escribe con eñe y no con ene.  Kristen, en cambio, rechaza usar la tilde.  La pregunté por qué, y me informó que ella «se casó con la cultura española, la divorció, y no le cae bien».  Claro, ese comentario me fastidió mucho por varias razones, pero mi pregunta hoy es: ¿es o no correcto escribir «Treviño» con ene en lugar de eñe?

My father has a girlfriend whose full name is “Kristen Treviño.”  “Kristen” is her given name, which comes from her American parents, and “Treviño” is her only family name, which she adopted upon marrying her Mexican ex-husband but that she kept even after the divorce since she shares it with her daughter.  Of course, in all Spanish-speaking countries, this name is written with the letter *ñ* and not with the letter *n*.  Kristen, on the other hand, refuses to use the tilde.  I asked her why, and she informed me that “she married the Spanish culture, she divorced it, and that she does not like it.”  Obviously, I took many issues with that comment, but my question today is this: is it or is it not correct to write “Treviño” as “Treviño”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No existe una regla que te obligue a escribir nombre y apellidos de una manera determinada, se escriben como son, nada más. Si el apellido es con eñe, se escribe con eñe, y si es con ene, con ene.
Mi primer apellido, por ejemplo, es **Sáez**. De este apellido existen muchas variaciones, por ejemplo Sáenz y Sáinz. Son variaciones que existen, no son incorrectas y yo he conocido a gente con esos apellidos.
La cuestión es que, aunque yo haya utilizado la palabra "variaciones" para describirlos, realmente no son variaciones, son **apellidos distintos**. Lo mismo se puede decir de nombres como Alberto, Roberto, Norberto, Adalberto; son todos nombres distintos.
Por eso no hay una regla que especifique cómo tienes que escribir tu apellido o tu nombre, por que los hay de todos los colores. Lo mismo pasaría aquí con las personas que tienen ascendencia de otros países y por tanto tienen apellidos extranjeros.

En cuanto a las cuestiones personales que explicas, no me voy a meter en ellas, aunque tenga mi opinión, porque este no es el sitio. Que la señora quiera escribir su apellido de otra forma y las razones que tenga para ello, no son nada que debiera discutirse en una página de preguntas y respuestas sobre el idioma castellano.

Sin embargo, hay algo que sí viene al caso y sí me gustaría decirte.
En mi opinión, el idioma no debería tratarse como una barrera que delimite y coarte lo que quieran hacer las personas, el idioma es un medio para expresar lo que quieres y que los demás lo entiendan, es una forma de comunicarse, no un conjunto de reglas hechas para joder o coartar.
Por tanto: es su apellido, que la señora lo escriba como le dé la gana.
Aparte de los posibles problemas porque los apellidos no concuerden en el papeleo legal, no veo el problema.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Nox. Estoy de acuerdo además en la parte final: que lo escriba como quiera, el límite puede ser la legalidad. En España cambiarse los apellidos es un follón y la transición de documentos puede dar dolores de cabeza por las posibles inconsistencias.

Comment: If Carlos Castaneda could get away with getting rid of the tilde, I guess Kristen can too.  Sure, it's irritating, but they do have the right.